# Embedding asp.net login to hand-written site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I have a login page created by another in ASP.net powered by msSQL (I don't know if I said this correctly, I no nothing of .NET)

I've started work adding a login drop-down box on a different website, coded by hand. Looking at the .aspx file for the original login page, I have absolutely no idea how to set this up on my hand-written site.

I was told to look up connectionstring, but I haven't really gotten anywhere with that.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? I played with the thought of embedded the asp login page through a frame... but I'm sure that's a terrible idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "hand written"? What technology are you building this site with?

Comment: Sorry I don't know too much. By handwritten I meant I am writing it in html.

Comment: Then no. What you are trying to accomplish is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net is a compiled framework, meaning you would generally have to 'build' and 'compile' before you can see the results - .aspx pages usually also have a aspx.cs code file behind it (depending on how it was coded). All the logic to make the .aspx page work is usually in the .cs file. I'm not sure what you mean by hand-written, but if you mean that you are coding it like a html page, this will not work...